# FFMPEG Hwaccel error with -hwaccel_output_format

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration, nvdec

I have Nvidia 1050Ti gpu

I test ffmpeg with cuda

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel nvdec -hwaccel_output_format cuda  -i input.mp4 -y  \ 
-c:v h264_nvenc -c:a libmp3lame -b:v 3M \
-filter_complex hwdownload,scale=w=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):h=ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),hwupload out.mp4
```

Error:

```
[hwupload @ 00000199b49c1080] A hardware device reference is required to upload frames to.
[Parsed_hwupload_2 @ 000001999ba8ee80] Query format failed for 'Parsed_hwupload_2': Invalid argument
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

I want full hardware transcode without using CPU.

Comment: Please note that the [tag:ffmpeg] tag states: "Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on [su] or [video.se]."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To transcode using hardware NVIDIA GPU, see:

- [NVIDIA FFmpeg Transcoding Guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/)
- [Using FFmpeg with NVIDIA GPU Hardware Acceleration](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/12.0/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/index.html)

You need to manual compile FFmpeg with the CUDA feature enabled. `scale` is a "software" filter using CPU resource. The hardware (GPU) equivalents (with limited options) are `scale_npp` and `scale_cuda`.

- `hwdownload`: send the frame down to RAM: GPU VRAM -> RAM.
- `hwupload`: inverse of `hwdownload` (RAM -> GPU VRAM). Notice: NVENC only works with GPU VRAM.